# ios Sqlite database - Select query

Tags: ios, sqlite

I have used following the Table(emp) in my product.

```
id  - name - Manager - dept- ismanager
101 - XXX  - YYY - 1-0
102 - XX   - YY  - 2-0
103 - XXX  - YYY - 1-0
104 - XX   - YY  - 2-0
105 - XXX  - kkk - 2-0
106 - XX   - zzz - 2-0
107 - XXX  - YYY - 2-0
```

I want to update the isManager column value as 1, when the manager is YYY/YY. because those are repeatable in my Table. How can I solve it? I have tried to check condition in where like "update emp SET ismanager = '1' where Manager = 'YYY' and Manager = 'YY'; but in that case table will hit many times and I dont know about the what the value stored in the manger column. It will change runtime. Basically i want to know, if the 'manager' column value is repeated, I will update 'ismanager' column as '1'.  Please Suggest me. How to do that?

This is, i can achieved as per CL(below) suggestion. Thanks CL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE emp
SET ismanager = 1
WHERE Manager IN (SELECT Manager
                  FROM emp
                  GROUP BY Manager
                  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```